# Unable to display content by using userID on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, userid

I am trying to display the content by using userID. I have a Firebase structure like this. By using `console.log(user.uid)` I can get userID. Based on that, how to display the title? Please, someone help me. I have a code like this:

```
    var url=("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/ saveReport.json");
    console.log('ffff1');
    var ref = new firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com');
    console.log('ffff2');
    // var url=('https://pwa-cssi.firebaseio.com/saveReport.json/Y6pCoSYnHmRP2wyITSoibY263RT2');
    ref.orderByChild("saveReport/userid").equalTo(true).on("value", 
    function(snapshot){
         console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
    })
```

And I have a Firebase structure like this. Please, help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get one item off of your database with a snapshot, use code like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('example/path/goes/here').once("value", dataSnapshot => {
 voteNum=dataSnapshot.val().voteNum
  })
```

An example of this code in use would be something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/'+key+'/votes/'+expoID).once("value", dataSnapshot => {
 voteNum=dataSnapshot.val().voteNum
  })
```

key and expoID being variables already defined. This code would grab the 'voteNum: 2' property in this photo.[image]

I really hope this helps solve your problem! If you have any problems ask me!

Comment: Hi...instead of key i have passed userid variable in the database.ref()but still   it shows the every records present in the structure.unable to display only corresponding userid values.

Comment: please could you suggest me where i am failing?...I need a help in urgent basis..

Comment: I think this would be because "ref.orderByChild("saveReport/userid")" will get a snapshot of every child. Try copying and pasting the code I gave you and replacing it with "ref.orderByChild("saveReport/userid").equalTo(true).on("value", 
    function(snapshot){
         console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
    })"